# How to modify a Plotly layout image using custom buttons to display or not an image

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to create two buttons on a plotly graph object to display or not an image but just the trace move not the image. I would like to display or not a background image.
Here the code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]))
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source="https://i.imgur.com/ebWhzmj.png",
        xref="paper", yref="paper",
        x=0.5, y=0.5,
        sizex=0.2, sizey=0.2,
        opacity=0.5,
        layer="below")
)
steps = [
    dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"visible": [False, True]},
              {"title": "No image"}],
        label="No image"
    ),
    dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"visible": [True, False]},
              {"title": "Image"}],
        label="Image"
    )
]
updatemenu = go.layout.Updatemenu(
    type="buttons",
    direction="down",
    showactive=True,
    buttons=list(steps)
)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[updatemenu],
    title="Image"
)
fig.show()
fig.write_html("test.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]))

# Add buttons that add shapes
image = [dict( source="https://i.imgur.com/ebWhzmj.png",
               x=0,
               y=1,
               xref="paper",
               yref="paper",
               sizex=0.5,
               sizey=0.5,
               opacity=1,
               layer="below")]

fig.update_layout(images=image)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            x=1.05,
            y=0.8,
            buttons=[
                dict(label="None",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=["images", []]),
                dict(label="Image",
                     method="relayout",
                     args=["images", image]
                     )])])

# Update remaining layout properties
fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=True,
)

fig.show()
```